# Retrieve all data from the respective model with rails ajax search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to implement ajax search to my rails application. So how do I proceed with my defined code.

index.html.erb

```
  <% @balance = 0 %>


     <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>


                <a href="#" class="toggle-form" style="float: right;" >Search</a>

                <div id="sample">

                <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, remote: true, method: :get, class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                <p>
                    <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", autofocus: true, class: "form-control-search" %>
                        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                    </p>
                    <% end %><br>
  </div>
                        <% if @xvaziris.empty? %>

                        <center><p><em>No results found.</em></p></center>              

                        <% end %>

                        <%= render @xvaziris %>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr  id = "kola" class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= xvaziri.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

</tr>
```

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
class XvazirisController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_xvaziri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.where (["description LIKE ? OR amount LIKE ? OR paid LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%"]) 
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html
        end 
    end

    def import
        Xvaziri.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to xvaziris_url, notice: "Xvaziris imported."
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new
    end

    def create
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new(xvaziri)
        if
            @xvaziri.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Created'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @xvaziri.update(xvaziri)
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Updated'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @xvaziri.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully destroyed.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def xvaziri
        params.require(:xvaziri).permit(:date, :description, :amount, :discount, :paid)
    end

end
```

I want to search for all the results from '/xvaziris' that is from @xvaziris without reloading the page.

index.js.erb

```
 <% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %>
  $('#kola').append("<%= j render xvaziri %>");
<% end %>
```

When I run the above codes, it get the error in my terminal as below;

[image: Screenshot-1.png]

and my index page styling and functioning got worse as shown below;

[image: Screenshot..png]

How should I write the above code in order to find searches in xvaziris#index ?

Comment: But where is the code for showing the data, you must have some code to display data right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is what I want to know in index.js.erb

Comment: as per your url request goes to create method , so you should add create.js.eb and render data there

Comment: Thanks but  when I create partial _xvaziri and inside index.js.erb when I put $('#sample').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'xvaziris/xvaziri') %>"); It searched fine but it is adding the last search to every newly searched items.Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: Not possible as I am short of 7 reputation score. Just I want to know what goes into index.js.erb file in order to find the records for @xvaziris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1.Create a file under `xvaziris` folder(I assume?): `_xvaziri.html.erb`. You need this file to render individual item eg:

```
<li> #Render individual xvaziris here </li>
```

**Notes:** I wrap content in `<li>`

2.In `index.js.erb`, add:

```
<% @xvaziris.each do |xvaziri| %>
  $(list_id).append("<%= j render xvaziri %>");
<% end %>
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried and now I have updated my index.html.erb file and other stuff. Please review and guide.

Comment: did you do step 1 as listed above?

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. Yes, I created _xvaziri.html.erb file and I updated my post, please review....

Comment: `which_id?` is the DOM element that you want to attach search results to. Because you wrap your item inside `<tr>` tag, that DOM element should be `<tbody>`. If you really want to understand how to handle ajax request, read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added,  id: 'search-form' in my form_tag and I put the same in index.js.erb. And I got the error as shown in an image.

Comment: @balance is not available in the the partial hence the error. Try to declare it in index.js.erb before the loop

Comment: Thanks. You are right but my partial _xvaziri.html.erb is been called mutliple times for one particular search.

Comment: Please refer the newly added descriptive images above.

Comment: Secondly, when I put this piece of code before making partial it worked fine but when I made the partial it doesn't work. which is as below;    <% if @xvaziris.empty? %>

                        <center><p><em>No results found.</em></p></center>              

                        <% end %>